# How to Customize the Default Bootstrap Style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am very new here and  with  bootstrap.I am having some problems to sort  my navbar.

```
 a{
    outline: 0;
    color: #fed136;
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fec503;
};

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

when i use code like this ,i can never change the navbar color BUT when i take 'a' block code under 'narbar-default' then it works.what's the reason it does not work like how i type ?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Also would be nice if you placed it into a jsfiddle

Comment: http://bootstrapdesigntools.com/tools/bootstrap-menu-builder/

Comment: Be sure your personal stylesheet is called after bootstrap.css